# UWP continuous speech recognition

Tags: c#, uwp, voice-recognition

I'm creating a smart mirror application using UWP, I want the user to use their voice to control the app. So far, I made a simple program to test speech recognition, it can work, but I want only when the app hear the key word-"Jason", then it  would start to convert the speech to text (I called my smart mirror Jason) like: "Jason, show me some news",because after that I would pass the text massage to LUIS function. If the sentence doesn't start with "Jason" the app won't convert it to text. What should I do to achieve it?    '

```
    private SpeechRecognizer contSpeechRecognizer;
    private CoreDispatcher dispatcher;

    protected async override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        dispatcher = CoreWindow.GetForCurrentThread().Dispatcher;
        contSpeechRecognizer = new Windows.Media.SpeechRecognition.SpeechRecognizer();
        await contSpeechRecognizer.CompileConstraintsAsync();  
        contSpeechRecognizer.ContinuousRecognitionSession.ResultGenerated +=ContinuousRecognitionSession_ResultGenerated;
        contSpeechRecognizer.ContinuousRecognitionSession.AutoStopSilenceTimeout = TimeSpan.FromDays(1);
        contSpeechRecognizer.ContinuousRecognitionSession.Completed += ContinuousRecognitionSession_Completed;   
        await contSpeechRecognizer.ContinuousRecognitionSession.StartAsync();
    }

    private async void ContinuousRecognitionSession_Completed(SpeechContinuousRecognitionSession sender, SpeechContinuousRecognitionCompletedEventArgs args)
    {
        await contSpeechRecognizer.ContinuousRecognitionSession.StartAsync();
    }

    private async void ContinuousRecognitionSession_ResultGenerated( SpeechContinuousRecognitionSession sender, SpeechContinuousRecognitionResultGeneratedEventArgs args)
    {           
        await dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
        {  
            SpeechResult.Text = args.Result.Text;
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to use "Jason" as a trigger, you can just add

```
if(speechResult.Contains("Jason")||speechResult.Contains("jason"))
{//Pass the Result to LUIS}
```